# Format BigDecimal number with commas upto 2 decimal places

Tags: java, android, formatting, bigdecimal

I want to format BigDecimal numbers with comma and 2 decimal places.
If the decimal values in BigDecimal number are 0 then I want to remove the trailing zeros also.
E.g
Amount is 20000.00 and should be formatted to 20,000
Amount is 167.50 and should be formatted to 167.50
Amount is 20000.75 and should be formatted to 20,000.75

I have used this method-

```
public static String getNumberFormattedString(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        if (bigDecimal != null) {
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
            return nf.format(bigDecimal);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

This is not returning correct output for big decimal input 167.50.
The formatted output is coming as 167.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NumberFormat` for what you want. Here is the function I use:

```
   public static String GenerateFormat(Double value) {
        if (value == null) return "";
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("de", "DE"));
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
        return nf.format(value);
    }
```

In this, you can see that I am providing Locale as a parameter for NumberFormat. Each country has its own number formatting standard, and what you want can be achieved with this locale  `new Locale("en", "US")`. Inside `setMaximumFractionDigits` you can place how much of fraction digits you want, in your case it is 2.

**EDIT**

Because of your situation, try this:

```
   public static String GenerateFormat(Double value) {
        if (value == null) return "";
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("de", "DE"));
        if (value%1 == 0) nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        else nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
        return nf.format(value);
    }
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you check that

Comment: you can set minimumFractionDigits to 2, and then you'll always have 2 digits. Also, what is "IN" as the second argument? Why not "US"?

Comment: "IN" stands for India. Also if I set minimumFractionDigits to 2, then for input 20000.00, the output is coming as 20,000.00. But I want the output as 20,000

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark it as solved and accept the answer